# i'm unable to get http-get response in OpenDayLight karaf console

Tags: http-get, karaf, opendaylight

as i'm new to this OpenDayLight, the following is my requirement

after installation of southbound plugin OVSDB in karaf console, i'm unable to get the http response from network-topology

installation is completely done by providing the following command in karaf console

```
feature:install odl-ovsdb-southbound-impl-ui
```

but after this installation,if i run the follow command

```
 GET  http://<controller-ip>:8181/restconf/config/network-topology:network-topology/topology/ovsdb:1/
```

or

```
GET  http://<controller-ip>:8181/restconf/operational/network-topology:network-topology/topology/ovsdb:1
```

the result body should be:

```
{
  "topology": [
   {
     "topology-id": "ovsdb:1"
   }
 ]
}
```

but the result of my console is showing only

```
INFO
```

please give me any idea to get resultant output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what ODL version are you using?

what tool are you using to issue the REST call?

I just tried with a very recent distribution (but I've known this to work
for a long time on much older versions as well):

```
opendaylight-user@root>feature:install odl-ovsdb-southbound-impl-ui
opendaylight-user@root>
```

then:

```
$ curl -u "admin:admin" http://127.0.0.1:8181/restconf/config/network-topology:network-topology/topology/ovsdb:1
```

which gave me:

```
{"topology":[{"topology-id":"ovsdb:1"}]}
```